# How to analyse a column with pandas that contains '-' [TypeError]

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, typeerror

I'm trying to analyse a spreadsheet using pandas. I have multiple sheets in a folder. For the purpose of making this work I am testing it on one spreadsheet for now, which I have named test.

I am trying to find the maximum_change, but my issue is that some of the cells in excel contain -, and not an integer or float.

I have tried to write something to ignore the -, but to no luck, as I still get TypeError

Here is code below for reference:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Define the folder path containing the Excel files
folder_path = r"C:\Users\Documents"

maximum_change = float('-inf')

def update_maximum_values(df):
        global maximum_change
        if 'change' in df.columns:
            maximum_change = max(maximum_change, df['change'].max())

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('test.xlsx'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

        change_df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Change')
        update_maximum_values(change_df)

        print(f"File: {filename}")
        if 'change' in change_df.columns:
            if 'change' in change_df.columns:
                print(f"Highest value in 'change': {round(change_df['change'].max(), 2)}")
        print()
```

This works fine when all the cells are filled with numbers

[this is the data I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWHxA.png)

I did try chatGPT where it suggested a solution using NaN, and to then ignore, but again it didn't really work and I couldn't debug it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before doing any operation in the loaded dataset, you could try to eliminate the invalid values from the target column.

`change_df['change'] = pd.to_numeric(change_df['change'], errors='coerce')`

This will convert all invalid values in the column into `NaN`. At this point, calling `change_df['change'].max()` will fail due to these `NaN`s. We can just filter them out before calling `max`, like this:

`change_df['change'].dropna().max()`

Comment: It's a bit strange, because without the '-' this runs fine, however when adding them and adding change_df['change'].dropna().max(), it returns AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Comment: This was solved by assigning a variable to change_df['change'].dropna().max()

Answer (score 0):

**df.max()** function won't work if there is **NaN values**. You can avoid this problem 2 different ways.

You can use **fillna()** function to filling your NaN values with any type of value or you can use **dropna()**.Both will help u to get your max() value.
However, If you want to keep your row that has NaN values the best option is to use **fillna().**

Comment: Please use `code formatting` (single `\``) for code, not **bold** (double `*`)

Comment: Similar to above,  without the '-' this runs fine, however when adding them and adding change_df['change'].dropna().max(), or fillna(0) it returns AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Comment: df['change'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Change'], errors='coerce') it will remove  where your row has  "-".